# removing files created by device_create(), class_create() and alloc_chrdev_region()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

After creating a character device driver using `alloc_chrdev_region()`, `cdev_init()`, `cdev_add()`, `class_create()` and `device_create()` I am unable to successfully clean all the entries made by the functions above in the `module_exit()`. When I use `rmmod` it just says "Killed". When I check the */proc/devices/*, */sys/class/* and */dev/* directories my created files are still present.
How can I make a clean exit of my module?
The code I am using for exit:

```
static void char_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "leaving the kernel.");
    cdev_del(my_chardev);

    device_destroy(myclass,first);

    class_destroy(myclass);

    unregister_chrdev_region(first,1);
}
```

For some reason it's not working.

Comment: Don't forget to add `\n` to [printk](https://lwn.net/Articles/503430/). More info about [debugging by printing](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing).

Comment: It is likely your device driver is still being used when you try to remove the module.  Don't forget to 'close' the device after 'open' in your user program etc.

Comment: So as soon as I insert it and then try to remove it crashes..I dont know how I can check if its been used in the exit module. Is there any way I could do that??

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where is it crashing? As for telling if the module is currently being used by something else, you should receive a warning when you run 'rmmod' if something else is using it or if it is running.  Also, make sure to check all of your error/return codes, its possible something failing but you are missing it.

Answer (score 1):

I can see there is an issue in order in which you are trying to destroy/del the class, device and cdev.

## I tried on my system with sample code. Snapshot attached below:

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]# find / -name sample_cdev0

/dev/sample_cdev0

/sys/devices/virtual/sample/sample_cdev0

/sys/class/sample/sample_cdev0

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]#

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]#

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]# rmmod himschar

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]# find / -name sample_cdev0

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]# cat /proc/devices | grep -i sample

[root@dhcp-10-123-181-110 own_char]#

========================================================================

The order you need to follow is:

```
    device_destroy(sample_class, sample_dev_t);
    class_destroy(sample_class);
    cdev_del(sample_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(sample_dev_t, 1);
```